# How to encode Response.StatusDescription or all response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, response, antixsslibrary

How to encode text, that I inserted in Response.StatusDescription in Asp.Net?
I cannot to use standard HttpEncoder.HeaderNameValueEncode method, but I need make the same like in this method?
And when I use

```
 Response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(...)
```

I need to avoid Reflected Xss vulnerability. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @stuartd ,well, I set up a StatusDescription: response.statusDescription = sometext. But it is the Reflected XSS vulnerability and I need to encode or escape "sometext". For example  AntiXssEncoder,HtmlEncode(sometext) - this code encodes html code. But I need to encode Header Value.